# "You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>" despite available BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, react-router

When trying to deploy my website, I am facing the following error:

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Switch`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Switch (created by SignIn)
    in div (created by SignIn)
    in div (created by SignIn)
    in SignIn (created by LogonPage)
    in div (created by LogonPage)
    in div (created by LogonPage)
    in LogonPage
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider
```

along with

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>
```

Usually I would be quite sure what the problem is - A missing Router somewhere in the parents of the affected node.

However, in my case the SignIn render looks like this:

```
    return (
        <div className="signInContainer container">
            <div className="signInMethodPicker row">
                <Link to="/register" className="signInMethodBtn registerBtn col">{Translation.Register}</Link>
                <Link to="/login" className="signInMethodBtn loginBtn col">{Translation.Login}</Link>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={props => <RegisterDialog {...props} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/register" render={props => <RegisterDialog {...props} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" render={props => <LoginDialog {...props} />} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

and a given Router at the entry point here:

```
$(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <LogonPage />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById("logonPageHolder"));
});
```

The Router is imported like this: 
`import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

There is a layer in between, but considering I just recently rewrote my app and it previously worked I don't see what could be going wrong.

In the light of my recent rewrite I highly suspect this problem being based on weird versioning, but I still need some guidance to resolve this, as researching for this error usually only gives me results which point to problems where people actually forgot to render a `<Router`> component, which is not the case here.

Comment: Please show how you are importing BrowserRouter

Comment: Could you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That would help to better understand your issue. You can create a small example on CodeSandbox. https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Added the import statement!

Comment: Please also explain the significance of the wrapping $() around the base render statement.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky As far as I remember of the time when I wrote this, I just wanted to postpone building my components until the page is loaded. I just checked it, it is not significant

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the Switch with BrowserRouter or other alternatives like HashRouter, MemoryRouter.

Try doing this rather

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And then wrap everything like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Switch>
  //your routes here
 </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: My bad if this caused possible confusion, but the SingIn component is rendered inside the LogOnPage, so there is technically already a BrowserRouter in the render tree I think, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show a link on a page or any element outside a `BrowserRouter` you will get such an error message.

Your error is saying any component that is not a child of a `Router` cannot contain any React Router related components.

Check your hierarchy, in React-Redux, hierarchy very important.

I always ensure that hierarchy goes like this: Provider->App->BrowserRouter.

So in your `SignIn` or `LogIn` component, where you have those `Link` and `Switch` tags you need to import like so:

```
import { Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

And then that component needs to go within `<BrowserRouter>` elements.